# ElasticSearch returns no result on bool filter containing dash

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed 2 objects (ES 1.5)

```
{
    tags: ["tag1","bla-bla"]
}

{
    tags: ["tag2"]
}
```

If I make this request:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should":
                    [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "tags": "bla-bla"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Elastic return **no result** because there is **"-"** in "tags" field.

If I search this, it works, I have 1 result:

```
...
    "term": {
         "tags": "tag1"
    }
...
```

Can someone explain why when I put a dash ("-") in the "tags" field, there is no result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not specified a custom one Elasticsearch will use [Standart Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) to analyze fields. And standart analyzer will remove punctions (`-` in your case) and tokenize your terms as [`tag1`, `bla`].

You can check analyzed forms with [term vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html):

```
GET <index>/<type>/<id>/_termvectors?fields=tags
```

Comment: Thanks, I added '"index" : "not_analyzed"' in the mapping, on the tags field, now it works.